# CSV file upload validator not working on windows (Chrome and firefox)

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I used jQuery Validate plugin to validate the CSV file while uploading.    I have the following code in my js file.

```
$("#selector").validate({
    rules: { file_csv: { accept: true, accept: "csv" }},
    messages: {
      file_csv: {accept: 'Please upload a csv file!'}
    }
});
```

On ubuntu (both firefox and chrome), It vaidates the CSV file and forward to the next phase of code. But for windows it throws the error of "Please upload a csv file!".

Comment: add a console log to check if its reporting any issues

Comment: Include the relevant HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code formatted for troubleshooting readability:

```
$("#selector").validate({
    rules: {
        file_csv: {
            required: true, 
            extension: "csv"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        file_csv: {
            accept: 'Please upload a csv file!' // <-- 'accept' rule not used
        }
    }
});
```

Your code contains one obvious error...

You are specifying the error message for a rule that you are not using.  Your error message is specified for the `accept` method, but you're only using the `required` and `extension` methods.  I'm not sure how this could be working in any browser.

This code should work perfectly:

```
$("#selector").validate({
    rules: {
        file_csv: {
            required: true, 
            extension: "csv"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        file_csv: {
            extension: 'Please upload a csv file!' 
        }
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT**:

If validating by file extension is not strong enough, you can validate by `mime-type` with [the `accept` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/).  However, you'll need to specify a valid `mime-type` for CSV files, which is `text/csv`.  See:  http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Toward_standardization

```
$("#selector").validate({
    rules: {
        file_csv: {
            required: true, 
            accept: "text/csv"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        file_csv: {
            accept: 'Please upload a csv file!' 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is regretful. I have just changed it to the original code. please have a look now. This is not working on windows works perfectly on ubuntu.

Comment: @MehakpalSingh, You should have instead changed it to my recommended code.  The `extension` rule is for file extensions and `accept` is only for mime types.  "CSV" is a file extension!

Comment: thanks for the reply.The problem is that if I use extension then it will accept any file with csv extension. I need the validater that accepts the file that is actually CSV.

Comment: @MehakpalSingh, if you must use the `accept` rule, then you have to specify a valid `mime-type` for CSV files.  The `mime-type` then needs to be `text/csv`